# ipad/iphone app with fixed background image

Tags: ios

I'm working on an app and I'd really like to have a fixed background image for the duration of the application.  Right now I rotate through different viewControllers which all have the same image, but I want  the background to remain fixed while the old buttons slide off and the new buttons slide on.  Any ideas?  Much like the home screen of iPhone/iPad, I want a "wallpaper" that is fixed while the screens change over the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set default image as a background image of root window from app delegate like this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

        // do stuff

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Couldn't quiet figure it out.

Comment: The way iOS7 pushes view controllers (sliding in from the side), could make the transitions look very strange with if there is a transparency on the viewcontroller's main view, because you'll be able to see a partial view of the disappearing viewcontroller, when the new viewcontroller slides in above.  That makes it necessary to make viewcontrollers that are pushed have a non-transparent background, thus you can't see through to the parent window's background -- unless you don't do any "push" viewcontroller transitions.